# Problem using variable in a Query

Tags: android, sqlite

I am banging my head over this for several hours, I tested many ways and I know where the proble is, but I just can't figure out how to fix it, I need an external point of view here.

That's my query code:

`public Cursor getAllExpensesUser(int user){

    String sql = "SELECT * FROM expense WHERE _id IN (SELECT id_expense FROM forwho WHERE   id_user = "+ user +")"; 
    return mDb.rawQuery(sql, null);
    }`

With this query it returns nothing.

When using the following query it returns my desired rows... obviously im using the id number directly.

```
`String sql = "SELECT * FROM expense WHERE _id IN (SELECT id_expense FROM forwho WHERE id_user = 2)";`
```

I have tried also with arguments:

`public Cursor getAllExpensesUser(int user){

    String sql = "SELECT * FROM expense WHERE _id IN (SELECT id_expense FROM forwho WHERE id_user = ?)";
    String[] arguments = {Integer.toString(user)};
    return mDb.rawQuery(sql, arguments);`

So bacically the problem is when I am using a variable.

Can anyone see where I am messing it up?

Thank you

Comment: I would set a breakpoint before you generate this query to see what the "user" variable actually has in it.  Maybe it didn't get loaded with information yet.

Comment: what type did you store in there?  integer or string?  in your last example you are looking for a match to a string.  drop the Integer.toString() and try it again.  but i have no idea why the first example doesn't work.

Comment: @andrew Good call.  I think SQL would still work in that case though, but it's worth checking

Comment: sqlite is complicated http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html but i agree, it looks likes it should work.

Comment: check out `mQuery` member of the `Cursor` you get when calling `getAllExpensesUser` - it should contain the query being run and might give you some clue of whats wrong. Also - does your query with args work?

Comment: The query with args doesn't work,  it only works if I don't use a variable and put the id number in the query, when I change it back to a variable, it messes it up....

Answer (score 0):

It should be `WHERE id_user = '" + user + "')";`

SQL requires single quotes around data on the right of the equals.

Comment: That is not true of numbers, id_user is an integer field it seems (based on his example and code)

Comment: My type for id_user is Integer, I am sure that I am passing the right data, I've confirmed it with a Toast. I also taught that the first example should of worked, that's why I am banging my head. I did a wipe of the emulator and will try again, I have seen in the pass some sort of corruption on the DB and some issue like this got fixed with a wipe... will keep you posted, if anyone should have other suggestions, please feel free

Comment: Well the wipe didn't help... any one got an idea?

Comment: Ok so apparently it is a problem with the data being send with the variable, when I send the data the variable id_user = 4, on the other side id_user = 0...  Now it's on me to figure out why the data is lost in transition.  Thank you all for you help!!!

Answer (score 0):

try to replace

```
String sql = "SELECT * FROM expense WHERE _id IN (SELECT id_expense FROM forwho WHERE id_user = "+ user +")";
```

with

```
String sql = new String("SELECT * FROM expense WHERE _id IN (SELECT id_expense FROM forwho WHERE id_user = "+ String.valueOf(user) +")");
```

**EDIT:** use `String.valueOf` instead of `Integer.toString`

Comment: Asahi, I tried... but it still doesn't want to show my expense, again, replacing the variable by the userID number 4 it works, and I know the variable equals 4 because before sending the call I confirm it with a Toast.  This is killing me, apparently I am not the only one struggling... Keep bringing ideas guys :)